# Override class and inject dependecys

Tags: magento2.3, php

I have following problem. I am overriding `\Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped` with this way:

First i override it in the `di.xml`

```
 <preference for="Custom\Class\Block\Grouped\Kachel" type="Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped" />
```

Everything works fine like this:

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Class\Block\Grouped;


class Kachel extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped {

  public function someCustomFunc(){

  }

}
```

But i get alot of errors if i try to inject some dependecys:

```
namespace Custom\Class\Block\Grouped;

protected $_storeManager;
public function __construct(
   \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
){
   $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
}

class Kachel extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped {

  public function someCustomFunc(){

  }

}
```

How can i for example add this storemanager to my class here?

Is it also possible to extend this class with some other custom class?

Comment: You need to call the parent construct and add you custom dependencies

Comment: @Shankar is it possible to inject other custom classes?

Comment: Yes its possible